# How to add user name and password to ksh bash file proxy configuration?

Tags: unix, proxy, ksh

I have a bash file to download a file but i do not know how to set username and password.
How can i add usename and password to proxy?

```
echo Current Name is $FILENAAM

/usr/sfw/bin/wget --execute=http_proxy=proxysrv:8080 -q -O /tmp/f.zip -c    "http://www.michdraft.net${FILENAAM}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
wget --http-user=USER --http-password=PASS  <YOUR_URL>
```

Comment: when i execute the file i get following error:`**/tmp/f.zip: Permissin denied**`

Comment: If there's a file owned by another user called /tmp/f.zip, then you will have problems writing to it.